# mysql access denied in c# code, but not in dsn

Tags: c#, mysql

I created an ODBC dsn on my local box to connect to a remote mysql instance, and when I test the dsn, it connects fine. I am trying to use the same dsn using C# but get "read access denied for user testuser@10.10.0.etc"

What do I need to do to successfully connect to mysql using my program (c#) thank you,

Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your connection string? There are difference between the single Libraries. You can see examples of those at [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/mysql).

Comment: No luck -- ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.38-community]SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'1.1.1.1' for table 'tablename'

Comment: I'm referencing a DSN, nothing changes, except when i try to execute a select statement from my console program, I ge the above "no permissions message"

Comment: Then the connection seems to be right, as there is an access denied message. Can you connect to the database using another tool (like http://www.mysql.de/downloads/workbench/)? Maybe there is a problem with this users rights.

Comment: I switched gears and installed "mysql-connector" and that worked just fine. thanks for the help jb, I'll mark it as the accepted answer,